# How does MySQL store the row data internally?

Tags: mysql, innodb, storage

Does a RDBMS store the row data one after another in a data block? Once data block is full, is the new block assigned continuous?

Per my understanding when table is created,  DBMS vendor must be keeping the some number of contiguous blocks reserved for a table. Once 
that chunk of blocks is full, another set of contiguous blocks must be assigned to that table. Isn't it? It will help the DBMS to efficiently
read the range scan.

So to me looks like answer to  first question is certainly yes. For second question it is yes till it has blocks available.

I have got some idea from Oracle which is more or less similar to my understanding

Comment: There's a [long answer](https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/02/on-learning-innodb-a-journey-to-the-core/) and some [internal official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb.html). I think you're at least partially right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:  Read about BTrees.  Better yet, read about the B+Tree variant, since that is what InnoDB uses.  (I recommend Wikipedia.)

The data is ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY` in one B+Tree.

Each secondary key is ordered by that key in another B+Tree, with the leaf nodes containing the Primary Key column(s) so that it can reach over into the data B+Tree to get the whole record.

Yes, there are blocks, but no they are not necessarily consecutive.  Instead, the B+Tree has a mechanism to provide a "tree" to find any particular block *and* for finding the 'next' and 'previous' blocks.

Within a 16KB block is several "rows", plus block overhead, row overhead, and column overhead.  A block contains info for only one table (or one secondary index).

When *any* operation is performed on a column in a row, the following steps occur:

1. Fetch the entire block from disk.  Often, the block is already cached in the "buffer_pool", so this step is fast.
2. Locate the row in the block.  Or the place in the block where the `PRIMARY KEY` says it should be.
3. Depending on the operation:

   - For `SELECT`, fetch the desired column(s).
   - For `INSERT`, the row is inserted.  If this makes the block too big, then a "block split" occurs.
   - For `DELETE`, the row is deleted.  This could lead to merging two blocks together.
   - For `UPDATE`, a new copy of the row is made.  If it is bigger or smaller, then the above steps may happen.
4. The block is marked as "dirty".  Eventually, it will be written back to disk.

I left out transactional 'ACID', index details, etc.

Caveat:  What I have said applies to MySQL's InnoDB.  And it does not apply to `FULLTEXT` or `SPATIAL` indexes.  Other vendors do other things.

Comment: Rick my basic question is how data is stored for a table . I believe block reserved for a table will store data only for that table not for other table.
Is that right ?

Comment: @user3198603 - Correct.  A 16KB block will contain data for only one table.  (More specifically for either data or secondary index for that table.)  Disk allocation is a bunch of compromises...  16KB is bigger than the OS "block" size; tiny tables "waste" a lot of space; tables are segregated; indexes are segregated; some blocks are prematurely allocated; blocks are not (in general) released back to the OS; etc.

Comment: Thanks. One related point is even If i have to update one specific field of row/column, first I have to read complete block containing that row and write back the complete content to that block. Right ?

Comment: @user3198603 - Correct.  See what I added.

Comment: @user3198603 - If you want to drill down some narrower topic, start a new Question.  This one is threatening to get out of hand.

Comment: Slightly Off-topic: When index is used on a non-key attribute(assuming it contains duplicates) then, is a B+ tree created with on that non-key attribute with the leaf nodes containing the Primary Key column(s) too? If yes, then would the next search on that primary key be an O(N*log(total records)) operation where N is number of records that match the query condition. N*log(total records) bcz these N records can have vastly different primary keys and log(total rec) time for each search. Am I right?

Comment: @ajaysinghnegi - All InnoDB indexes contain the PK column(s) in the leaves -- in order to reach into data's B+Tree [if needed] to get the rest of the columns.  So, yes, there is a NLogN lookup for other columns.  (This leads to a strong argument against using UUIDs for the PK!)  Generally, the NLogN argument is less critical than "counting the disk blocks that needed to be read".  (Rule of Thumb:  each index or data block contains 100 index or data rows.)

Comment: `Generally, the NLogN argument is less critical than "counting the disk blocks that needed to be read".` Ain't both the same? After we get the PK from the non-key attribute through a B+ tree blocks, these PKs can be present in different blocks. Yes, if many PKs reside in same blocks then the block count matters(which usually is the case).

Comment: Blocks are cached in the "buffer_pool".  Reading from disk is the costly part; after that the NLogN is essentially CPU time, which is rather small.

Comment: @RickJames But blocks will be cached in the "buffer_pool" only when they have been brought in there. Before that, there must be some query that asks for such blocks. So, after we get to know the PKs(from the non-key attribute via the index) which are scattered across different blocks, fetching the blocks from disk where these PKs reside is what makes the operation expensive.

Comment: Only thing to ask-suppose id is a PK and id=1,2 both reside in the same block. After the db has fetched the block containing id=1 into buf_pool, how does it know that id=2 is also in one of the buffered-blocks without again going through the indx or does it have to go through the index again to know that(which is not that expensive though)? One more thing to ask - `All InnoDB indexes contain the PK column(s) in the leaves` - is it possible for databases to index on a non-key attribute with leaves containing the pointer to the actual row blocks? I guess, we'll have to duplicate the data though.

Comment: @ajaysinghnegi - No assumptions about blocks, gaps, etc, are made.  It will do a LogN drill-down to file id=2, ignoring that id=1 was just found.  On the other hand, if you do "WHERE id >=789", it will do the drilldown to find id=789 (O(LogN)), then walk forward (O(1)) to find whatever ids are next.  This is where the "+" of "B+Tree" comes into play.